# Search API / Facets: How can I define a range / manipulate the search query in D8?

Tags: 8, search

I've defined a facet for the field "Authored on". I'd like to create display filters like "current week", "current month", etc. on my website.

The creation of the links was no problem. I have facet links like this:

```
<a href="/news?period=current_week">Current week</a>
```

How can I manipulate the search query if a period has been selected? I need something like "get all search results, which are younger than tstamp of monday this week" or "get all search results between date X and date Y".

Answer (score 3):

Afterwards here my solution: I've solved it with condition groups in the hook_search_api_query_alter() function:

```
function MYMODULE_search_api_query_alter($query) {
    //...

    $conditionGroup = $query->createConditionGroup('AND');
    $conditionGroup->addCondition('created', $firstDayOfYear, '>=');
    $conditionGroup->addCondition('created', $lastDayOfYear, '<=');
    $query->addConditionGroup($conditionGroup);

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this easily to my knowledge.

I recently looked at the Search API (7x) module for similar functionality and basically you can do preconfigured Ranges using these modules:

(7x) https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_ranges  this modules treats a range value as a numeric values, which dates are essentially not. Converting to timestamps is a pita.

(7x) the Search API does not support the `BETWEEN` operator of Solr yet directly for Views integration. See https://www.drupal.org/node/1783746

The only alternative I've found for date searching with Solr (using Search API) is basically 2 exposed filters in Views going off of an Indexed date field in Solr. And then configuring the filter to use the date_popup widget for a nice calendar with day, month and year selection options -- but it's not a simple range or slider widget.

You may get better mileage from the Apache Solr module instead of Search API but I use the Search API module because I can see with little effort it supports Solr 5.x in the module include files.